# declare module for each file or use the app module for all files?

Tags: angularjs

I started learning angularjs and I see 2 types of module uses and I cant understand when to use this and when this:

example1:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Comment', function($http) {
}
app.controller('mainController',  function($scope, $http, Comment) {
}
```

or
example2:

```
angular.module('commentService', [])
.factory('Comment', function($http) {
}

angular.module('mainCtrl', [])
.controller('mainController',  function($scope, $http, Comment) {
}

var app = angular.module('app', ['commentService','mainCtrl']);
```

sometimes I see module declarion in each file(services factory controllers and so on)
and sometimes I see using the app module in those files, what is the right way? and why both of them works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, if you're concerned about app organization, read the discussion on the [yeoman-generator-angular issue board](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/109) from about a year ago. There's way more wisdom there than you could feasibly expect to get in a SO answer.That said, I'll try to provide an answer that's more pertinent to your specific concern, and (marginally) more concise.

**DO NOT** make a module for a single controller like `angular.module('MainCtrl',[]).controller('MainCtrl')`, or even a set of controllers who are only related in that they are all controllers:

```
angular.module('appCtrl', [])
    .controller('appleController', function ($scope) {})
    .controller('orangeController', function ($scope) {})
    .controller('unicornController', function ($scope) {})
;
```

Why is this a bad idea? First, by definition, it's categorical, not modular; modules are groupings of system components which are related *topically*, not *conceptually*. When you're building a car, you don't put in *all of the nuts and bolts* at once. You put in the nuts and bolts that hold together the module that you're building. Controllers are like nuts and bolts. An engine is like a module.

Second, now you have to inject the `appCtrl` module anywhere that you want access to a controller. That's just a mess for developers to have to deal with; they're always digging through the code trying to find "whatever that module with that one thing in it" was, or they'll just repeat code all over the place.

Dependency Injection in AngularJS is less a rule than a (clever and awesome) string manipulation hack, and JavaScript has no "namespacing" system in the classical sense. Creating modules like `app.products` or `app.cart` is more for the developer's convenience and/or controlling the release cycle than making the program "work".

For these and other reasons, I caution developers against "Premature Modularization". If you're writing something app-specific---that is, you won't be reusing it right now in another app---why not just attach it to your app module? Then you have access to it anywhere in your app that you want it. (There are of course complexities that might cause you to change this, but if/when those do arise *that's* when you modularize).

Structure your directories by feature (Angular conventions do condone BDD, after all):

```
 |-app/
 |-|-cart/
 |-|-|-CartItemsModel.js
 |-|-|-OrderRepository.js
 |-|-|-cart.html
 |-|-|-add-item-modal/
 |-##some more cart stuff
 |-|-checkout/
 |-|-|-confirmation/
 |-|-|-|-confirmation.html
 |-|-|-|-confirmation.less
```

If you're writing feature files or getting acceptance criteria from your employer, you can even model your directory structure directly after those features or requirement sets. That makes everything smooth from defining the scope of an iteration through documentation through revisiting code at a later time.

Comment: if I go with the directory structure example that you gave its mean that I need to include all this files in my html? <script src="app/cart/cartItemModel.ks"> <script src="app/cart/orderReposi.js"> and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Both example work. But for instance with the example 2, this syntax can be used for separation of concern. You may need a module that is responsible for providing services which gives you function for Rest calls. Or another module that package some directives.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered good practice to segregate your modules into different files. This will ensure that you are practicing good code control, and gives your code a greater degree of portability and debug-ability. Instead of declaring modules in the same file, declare them in different files with their module name.

It's good practice to segregate your files based on their module-controller relationship -- that is, each *controller* should have its own file, like this:

```
\scripts\controllers\
- - main.js
- - comments.js
```

Then, inside your `main.js` file, you'll start off with the controller declaration:

```
//main.js
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    // Controller-scope stuff here
});
```

Finally, inside your `comments.js` file:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('CommentsController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    // Comment controller code
});
```

One way to help with organization right off the bat is to organize your files is with a seed template, like [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

Just remember that you want to keep your `module('app').controller('whatever')` inside `whatever.js`, and any other `.factory('forWhatever')` (like in your example) should be contained with that parent `.controller('whatever')` inside the `whatever.js` file.